# Eclipse IDE not working with Google back up and sync

Tags: java, eclipse, google-drive-api, synchronization, backup

I run 2 computers  and sync the data between them using Google back up and sync which effectively stores everything on my google drive.

I have updated a class on my laptop and when I go on my desktop to continue it comes up with the old code however when I open the class file up on notepad it contains the updated file.

How do I get my eclipse to run the updated files I thought it should do this automatically since the file has been changed from the sync?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Workspace_ is the checkbox _Refresh using native hooks or pooling_ checked?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Workspace preference page to have it automatically Refresh the workspace for you.